# How to write .install file for a custom module

Tags: 7, hooks, installation

I am new to drupal and want to write a .install file for my custom module. here is the code of my module.

```
function formModule_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['form/formModule'] = array( //this creates a URL that will call this form at "examples/form-example"
    'title' => 'Form', //page title
    'description' => 'A form with a text field and Submit button.',
    'page callback' => 'formModule_intro', //this is the function that will be called when the page is accessed.  for a form, use drupal_get_form

    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'expanded' => TRUE,
  );

  $items['form/formModule/form1'] = array(
    'title' => 'Form One',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('formModule_form'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'weight' => 1,
  );


  $items['form/formModule/form2'] = array(
    'title' => 'Form Two',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('formModule_formOne_one'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'file' => 'formModule_formOne.inc',
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'weight' => 2,
  );
  return $items;
}


function formModule_form($form, &$form_state) {

 $result = db_query("SELECT n.nid, n.title FROM {node} n 
                         WHERE n.type = 'product'");

    $options = array();
   foreach($result as $row) {
      $options[$row->nid] = $row->title;
    }
    //dsm($options);



    $form['productid'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select', 
    '#title' => t('Select a product'), 
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#options' => $options,
    '#description' => t('Choose an option.'),
  );


  $form['stock'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield', //you can find a list of available types in the form api
    '#title' => 'Enter the stock',
    '#size' => 10,
    '#maxlength' => 10,
    '#description' => t('stock should be integer value'),
    '#required' => TRUE, //make this field required
  );



  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'submit',
  );

  return $form;
}


function formModule_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {

  if (!($form_state['values']['stock'] > 0)){
   form_set_error('stock', t('Stock must be a integer value only.'));
  }
}

function formModule_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {

global $user;

  // Here u can insert Your custom form values into your custom table.
  db_insert('formModule_stock')
    ->fields(array(
      'productid' => $form_state['values']['productid'],
      'stock' => $form_state['values']['stock'],


    ))->execute();
    drupal_set_message("successfully saved formModule_stock"); 

}
```

How do I create the table my module is using?

Comment: I dont think you need an install file for this. you use an install file only if you have to alter the tables or create a new table etc. for this you just need the modulename.module file

Comment: @MohammedShameem Think OP wants to create a new table for `formModule_stock` using .install file

Comment: yes i want to create new table

Comment: In Drupal 7, tables will be created automatically when you install it (and dropped automatically when you uninstall it). Add your table schema in the .install file. see hook_schema.

Comment: Have you tried [reading the documentation](http://drupal.org/node/876250)?

Comment: @aashi : did you get solution for this problem

Answer (score 5):

In Drupal 6, `hook_install()` is necessary to create the database tables used from the module; the code of that hook simply calls [drupal_install_schema()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_install_schema/6), which then invokes the implementation of [hook_schema()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!install.php/function/hook_schema/6) present in the installation file.
In Drupal 7, or higher, only `hook_schema()` is necessary to create the tables used from the module.

So, in both the cases, you implement `hook_schema()`. I would implement it as follows.

```
function formModule_schema() {
  $schema ['formModule_stock'] = array(
    'description' => 'The base table for stocks.',
    'fields' => array(
      'productid' => array(
        'description' => 'The primary identifier for a stock.',
        'type' => 'serial',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
      'stock' => array(
        'description' => 'The current stock value.',
        'type' => 'int',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => 0,
      ),
    ),
    'primary key' => array('productid'),
  );

  return $schema;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Probably you have already created the database for your module. In that case you might want to check out the [Schema module](http://drupal.org/project/schema), which helps you to create the array to be used in hook_schema().